# Why do I get "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region."?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

Why would my account not support the EC2-Classic Platform?

All I am trying to do is create a Redshift database and I cannot get my client to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounts created after a certain point can only use EC2-VPC. In addition some AWS regions (such as eu-central-1) only support EC2-VPC.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you refer to the message in the "Security Group" section in the Security:

> >
>   Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. Cluster Security Groups are only available when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your clusters. Go to the EC2 Console to view your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see Amazon Redshift Documentation on Supported Platforms and Managing Clusters in VPC.
>   <<

What this says is that you don't have to worry about setting up a Security Group for EC2-Classic. Instead use a Security Group from the VPC Security Groups.
You can select a Security Group for you Redshift cluster during create cluster or when you select to modify your cluster.
Depending on your kind of connection to your AWS VPC (through VPN or Direct Connect or over the public internet) you have to chose the correct source IP address. 
Let's assume you go over the public Internet, then Redshift needs to have a public IP and the Security Group has to allow traffic from your public IP to the port you specified for Redshift.
In case of VPN/DirectConnect a private IP would be most likely.

Answer (score 2):

Accounts created after 2013-12-04 support EC2-VPC only.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

All of you guys are right.

You should go to the "Security" option in the Redshift area, create a Subnet Group and attach it into one of your VPC (create one if you don't have yet).